# vue component react to changes in vue data object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have some raw html generated on the server side, and I would like this to be reactively updated using the Vue framework.

I first thought that v-html would do the job, but this doesn't work as v-html doesn't react to changes in vue data values.

Apparently components are one way of achieving this, however I can't quite figure out how to link the content of a component to the data of the Vue object.

---

Say I have a Vue data value called `table_html`, and this was a table ready to be rendered in the page, how would I create a component that would react to changes in `table_html`?

Here's something that doesn't work. (It seems that when calling self = this, self becomes the vue-component, how do I reference its parent? I.e. the `page` object?)

```
page = new Vue({

  components: {
    'table-element': {
      template: "<div>{{ table_html }}</div>",
      data: function() {
        self = this; // References the component, not the parent

        return self.table_html // How to reference the Vue bound data?

      }
    }
  },

  el: "#container",

  data: {
    table_html: "<table>...table contents </table>
  }
```

Comment: But `v-html` does react to data changes, check out this example https://jsfiddle.net/kjans7sz/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `props` to pass data from `parent` to the `child` component.
More details can be found on the official documentation.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props

```js
// Component declaration
Vue.component('table-element', {
    // declare the props
    props: ['tableHtml'],
    
    // just like data, the prop can be used inside templates
    // and is also made available in the vm as this.message
    template: '<div>{{ tableHtml }}</div>',
    
    data: function() {    
        self = this; 
        return self.tableHtml;
});


page = new Vue({

  el: "#container",

  data: {
    table_html: "<table>...table contents </table>
  }
  
 
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table-element v-bind:table-html = "table_html" ></table-element>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) `props` can be a good solution in communication parent- child components or recorder -direct registered child. remember that `props` is a variable data as data in a vue instante. 
2) you store data a object in javascript in global scope in your external js file , if you use it in passing data to offspring child in the architecture of html code- it isn't a elegant solution.
3) you can use vuex to control the communication of data in the architecture of components.